# How do ASIC designers approach designing for extremely low supply voltages like 0.3V?

Tags: mosfet, vlsi, power-consumption, asic, undervoltage

In ASIC design, there is a tradeoff between performance and energy efficiency.  Since most consumer CPU's are designed for maximum performance, they operate at high voltages and clock frequencies, have large caches, use complex branch predictors, and so on.  The cost is very high energy consumption per operation.

By contrast, Bitcoin mining ASIC's are designed for maximum energy efficiency.  Thus, they tend to make the opposite design choices.  For example, they use lower supply voltages, even if (as a result) their transistors need to switch more slowly and the clock frequency must be reduced.  This often reduces the key energy-per-operation metric because power consumption scales as \$fV^2\$.

As an extreme example, BitFury [advertises](https://bitfury.com/crypto-infrastructure/asic) that their most recent ASIC, "Clarke," can run at just 0.3V.  That seems really low to me, possibly even in the subthreshold regime; Clarke [is manufactured using UMC's 14nm process](https://breakermag.com/hit-by-crypto-winter-chip-foundry-umc-posts-quarterly-operating-loss/), which ordinarily [needs 0.8V](https://www.umc.com/en/Product/technologies/Detail/14nm).  So my question is: how would an ASIC designer approach designing an ASIC to operate at such a low supply voltage?

Comment: What would you say if I asked you what fuels can you put into an engine? Completely, utterly dependent on the design of the engine itself.

Comment: @DKNguyen, what factors influence the limit?  Is it mostly dependent on the ASIC design, or the semiconductor process?

Comment: The semiconductor process and how many transistors you decide to stack in a totem pole.

Comment: If there was one final answer to this question, then companies like BitFury wouldn't be out there advertising that they've improved on the previous state of the art.

Comment: Only desktop CPUs are power hungry these days. Most microcontrollers have a brownout or undervoltage lockout feature to prevent *unreliable operation* at low supply voltage conditions, to avoid data corruption. Without a datasheet I can't tell if they guarantee that *every* chip works from a 0.3V supply, or only that *one of the prototype  chips they once tested on the bench at room temperature* worked at 0.3V during one bench test experiment. Given this ASIC only runs bitcoin hashes, maybe the validation is simpler, or nobody notices if it sometimes fails?

Comment: As it stands this question is a bit like asking how long is a piece of string... since we can't tell what's technically behind BitFury's claim; (1) Is the question which aspects of the IC fabrication process affect MOSFET characteristics such as threshold voltage and gate capacitance? (2) Is the question how to experimentally validate a design or determine the minimum required supply voltage for 100% guaranteed correct operation? (3) Is the question how does an ASIC designer generally approach designing for very low supply voltages?

Comment: @MarkU, thanks, your comments helped me clarify my thought process.  I think my real question is closest to (3), how would an ASIC designer generally approach designing for very low supply voltages.  I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: The question is too broad.

Comment: I think the question is very reasonable.

Comment: _" For example, they use lower supply voltages, even if (as a result) their transistors need to switch more slowly and **the clock frequency must be reduced.**"_ - seems counterproductive for this application.

Comment: Great article which discusses sub threshold design, free to view : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx5/4563671/4785770/04785777.pdf?tp=&arnumber=4785777&isnumber=4785770&ref=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8=

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have confused energy and power. One major component of power consumption in CMOS digital circuits is the power required to switch signal capacitance, and this power is proportional to \$f\times V^2_{DD}\$.

However, **energy** is the integral of power over time. If you reduce the power consumption by half but need twice as long to perform the same computation then the energy remains the same.

The trick is to reduce power consumption while keeping the clock frequency high. If you are going to reduce the power supply voltage, you need to also decrease the transistor threshold voltage to be able to switch the capacitances quickly. It's difficult to precisely control the threshold voltage, so in some cases the MOSFET body voltage will be controlled dynamically to adjust the thresholds in real time.

However, at some point the power lost due to subthreshold leakage overwhelms the power gained by decreasing the supply voltage. It is not an easy game to play.

Answer (score 1):

Ultra low power CMOS is Samsung, TMSC, ST, TI, Apple, ARM and a few others business.

There are many approaches to reduce the power consumption of microprocessor or ASIC.

1. Subthreshold MOSFET's
2. Adiabatic logic

   [Wikipedia - Adiabatic circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_circuit):

   > Unlike traditional CMOS circuits, which dissipate energy during switching, adiabatic circuits reduce dissipation by following two key rules:
   >
   > - Never turn on a transistor when there is a voltage potential between the source and drain.
   > - Never turn off a transistor when current is flowing through it.
3. ARM's Mono project

   https://community.arm.com/developer/research/b/articles/posts/m0n0-a-flashback

Comment: Can you point to any examples of consumer-grade processor that use adiabatic logic? My impression is that this is almost entirely of academic interest.

Comment: Adiabatic logic hasn't yet reached consumer grade level.

Comment: This is outside my experience, but 0.3V would almost have to be subthreshold right?

Comment: I really can't say for sure. I trust big manufactures only. I wouldn't use that part. It's too early for sub 1 V circuits.